# Call other java class name from other class in same package

Tags: java

I have 5 classes namely c1, c2, c3, container ,main in same package.

From main class I am going to print class names of c1, c2. c3 is super class for c1 and c2.

I want to print as

my name is c1

my name is c2

super class is c3

but it prints only

my name is c3

my name is c3

super class is main

Here is my main class

```
    class main{
        public static void main(String[] argh) {
            Container cont= new Container();
            c3 o1 = cont.getc3("c1");
            c3 o2 = cont.getc3("c2");
            System.out.println("My name is: " + o1.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("My name is: " + o2.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("Our superclass is: " + o1.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());

        }
    }
```

Here is my container class

```
    class container extends main {

        private String name;

        public c3 getc3(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new c3(string);
        }

        public String getName() {
            System.out.println("-------------------------"+name);
            return name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

    }
```

Here is c3 class which is super class

```
class c3 extends main {

    private String name;
    private String string1;


    public c3(String string1) {
        string1 = string1;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

    public String getString1() {
        return string1;
    }

    public void setString1(String string1) {
        this.string1 = string1;
    }

}
```

Here is c1 class

```
class c1 extends c3{

    public c1(String string1) {
        super(string1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

here is c2

```
class c1 extends c3{

    public c2(String string1) {
        super(string1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getc3` method returns objects of `c3` class. The fact that you pass to it the Strings "c1" and "c2" doesn't make a difference.

You'll have to change the implementation of `public c3 getc3(String string)` if you wish it to return isntances of `c1` or `c2`. For example :

```
    public c3 getc3(String string) {
        if (string.equals("c1"))
            return new c1(string);
        else if (string.equals("c2"))
            return new c2(string);
        else
            return new c3(string);
    }
```

Comment: how to get them, can you assis here?